# Electric drum kit noise - cymbals only (Need advise to reduce noise)

Tags: drum-kits, noise, electronic-drumset

I have read lots of posts about electric drum noise especially in apartments, but these posts relate to the kick drum the the thump sound either upwards or downwards. 
emphasized text
I have experienced complaints from neighbours because of the rubber cymbal noise. I have a roland kit with **VH-11** and **CY-12C** cymbal pads.

Does anyone have any suggestions about reducing the noise on these?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: I have heard of people taping a think cloth to it, not sure how that will affect the sensitivity of the pad, but it would probably work in a pinch.

Comment: You have some very thin walls. Long term, I'm afraid your best option is to look forward to your next move and hopefully you can find a place where a reasonable (IMHO) amount of noise won't sound so loud to your neighbors. Regarding your question, where do the complaining neighbors live? Below? Above? On the same level? Adjacent to the room where the kit is or two rooms over?

Comment: Yeah, I can hear people coughing from the next apartment so drums are  not welcome. The complaining neighbours live above (i am ground floor), but I have neighbours on all sides of the apartment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method I used on a kit at school years ago is to simply put any cloth, in my case felt, on the cymbal. cut a circular hole in your cloth to attach it to the cymbal then just hang it over the cymbal. It's does not create the best results of all but it does minimize the noise of the sticks on the cymbals. the thicker the cloth the more noise reduction but the less response on the electronic cymbals if you go too far.

It's cheap and easy and works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

For the kick pedal(s) you can try building a "floating floor."

I have seen people who take two pieces of board separated by an array of tennis balls (usually held in place by means of small holes or collars.

Put a mat on the floor, put the floating boards on that mat and another mat ion top. This raises everything by maybe 4 inches, disperses the downward forces across a wider surface area, has a dampening effect. All of this should reduce the transmission of noise through the floor from the physical action of the pedals.

If you want to make a big enough platform, your whole kit can be decoupled from the floor which will reduce noise from the movement of the kit "scaffolding."

The cymbals are more complicated in that any dampening will result in potential trigger sensitivity issues. Maybe try moving the kit away from the shared wall. A very thick duvet hung as a tapestry might work to reduce any mid to high frequency transmission through the shared wall.

Comment: The key seems to be (at the floor interface) a rug or mat and then some form of thick high density, heavy material and then the decoupling (tennis balls etc). I just came across one individual who made a box and filled it with sand. Very heavy

Comment: I will attempt the riser as that can't hurt to reduce some noise. As the cymbals are attached to the rack, there is probably some impact noise going through the floor as well.